# How to pass a null variable into a Spring Expression in JSP

Tags: jsp, spring-el

I am using the `<spring:eval>` tag in a JSP:

`<spring:eval expression="'today is ' + today" />`

Where `today` is a java.util.Date.  Everything works just fine, as long as the today variable is not null.  When `today` is null, I get

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Field or property 'today' cannot be found on null
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:243)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:112)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:107)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpPlus.getValueInternal(OpPlus.java:70)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
    org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:98)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EvalTag.doEndTag(EvalTag.java:126)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.admin.inbox_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005feval_005f1(inbox_jsp.java:195)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.admin.inbox_jsp._jspService(inbox_jsp.java:120)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
    org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.JspRequest.doInclude(JspRequest.java:123)
    org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractViewRequest.dispatch(AbstractViewRequest.java:47)
    org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:45)
    org.apache.tiles.request.render.ChainedDelegateRenderer.render(ChainedDelegateRenderer.java:68)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:188)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.execute(InsertAttributeModel.java:132)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:299)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.common.main_002dlayout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f2(main_002dlayout_jsp.java:243)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.common.main_002dlayout_jsp._jspService(main_002dlayout_jsp.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.forward(ServletRequest.java:265)
    org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.doForward(ServletRequest.java:228)
    org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractClientRequest.dispatch(AbstractClientRequest.java:57)
    org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:45)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:397)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:238)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:221)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.DefinitionRenderer.render(DefinitionRenderer.java:59)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:145)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:152)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

So I tried checking for null with Elvis operator:

`<spring:eval expression="'today is ' + (today ?: 'null date!') "  />`

but that gives the exact same expression.  After stepping into the Spring PropertyOrFieldReference code with a debugger, what I found was that it does not seem to be able to handle null variables.

Plain old JSTL code handles the null by printing out nothing, which is fine:

`today is ${today}`

It also works just fine from SPeL if `today` is a property of a bean:

`<spring:eval expression="'today is ' + myBean.today"  />`

This yields the string "today is null" as expected.  In this trivial example, I could use JSTL to branch around my `<spring:eval>` tag when the variable is null, but what I really need to be able to do is to use `<spring:eval>` to execute a static function which has several variables, any of which can legitimately be null.  The problem is, SPeL does not seem to be able to correctly resolve a variable if it is null.

Comment: try `"'today is ' + (today is null?'null date!':today) " />` or even `'today is' + today?`

Comment: Thanks for the ideas - the first one fails to parse because `is` is not a keyword.  I think you've been doing too much SQL... :)  If I replace it with `==`, though, it fails with the same exception (for the same reason that the Elvis operator doesn't work).  The second one doesn't parse because it thinks the `?` is the beginning of a ternary operator.

Answer (score 2):

The EL is ok. The scope is not clear. Spring even cant find the variable.

Use this for request Scope:

```
<spring:eval expression="'today is ' + requestScope['today']" />
```

Use this for session Scope:

```
<spring:eval expression="'today is ' + sessionScope['today']" />
```

Comment: This does indeed get around the problem, so I thank you for that.  However, it seems odd (and a little unsettling) that I would only have to do this for variables that can potentially be null.  If the `today` variable has a non-null value, then Spring can resolve the bare variable name just fine.  This is what I would expect.  After all, in JSP EL, it first looks up identifiers in page scope, then request, session, etc.  If it can't find it, the expression evaluates to `null`.  It doesn't require you specify a scope.  Why wouldn't Spring be able to do this?

Comment: Actually, the crux of the problem seems to be a bug.  The canRead() method of org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EvalTag.JspPropertyAccessor relies on pageContext.findAttribute(). It assumes that if findAttribute() returns null, that the attribute was not set, and is thus unreadable. So it can't handle the case where the attribute is present, but with a null value. Perhaps a better test would be testing the return value of pageContext.getAttributesScope() to see if it is set in any scope (i.e. - return value > 0).